# Getting the first element of the array in Dwoo

Tags: php, template-engine, dwoo

I'm using template engine called Dwoo. How get the first element of the array without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{assign array("Bob" "John") users}
{$users.0}`

[Dwoo Wiki](http://wiki.dwoo.org/index.php/Array)